# R get object from global environment from function if object exists in global but use different default if not

Tags: r, function, environment-variables

Surely this is possible, but I can't seem to find how to do it:

I'd like to have a default of a function input, but override the default and get() a variable from the global environment if it exists in the global environment. If it doesn't exist in the global environment, take the default of the function, with **any setting in the function being top level and overriding them all.**

Ideally it would work like this made-up non-working function:

```
###Does not work, desired example

myfunc <- function(x=30){
if(exists.in.global.env(x)){x <- get(x)}
###Top level is tough
if(x.is.defined.as.function.input=TRUE ????){x <- x.defined.as.input}
}else{ x <- 30} 
return(x)
}
```

So that if I do:

```
myfunc()
[1] 30
```

But if I create x I want it to override the default x=30 of the function and take the global environment value instead:

```
x <- 100
myfunc()
[1] 100
```

But if I have x defined inside the function, I'd like that to be top level, i.e. override everything else even if x is defined globally:

```
x <- 100
myfunc(x=300)
[1] 300
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can modify your function to check if `x` exists in the `.GlobalEnv` and get it from there if it does, otherwise return the default value.

```
myfunc <- function(x = 30) {

  if ("x" %in% ls(envir = .GlobalEnv)) {
    get("x", envir = .GlobalEnv)
  } else {
    x
  }

}
```

So if `"x" %in% ls(envir = .GlobalEnv)` is `FALSE` it would return

```
myfunc()
[1] 30
```

If `x` is found it would return it. if `x <- 100`:

```
myfunc()
[1] 100
```

**Edit after comment**

If you want to make sure to only return `x` from the global environment if `x` is not specified as an argument to `myfunc`, you can use `missing()`. It returns `TRUE` if `x` was not passed and `FALSE` if it was:

```
myfunc <- function(x = 30) {

  if ("x" %in% ls(envir = .GlobalEnv) & missing(x)) {
    get("x", envir = .GlobalEnv)
  } else {
    x
  }

}
```

So for your example:

```
x <- 100
myfunc(x=300)
[1] 300
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but any idea how to do the last part? Keep the x if user defined away from the default? ie. x<-100; myfunc(x=300) returns 300?

Comment: Thanks! Within a function missing() would apply to solely the environment within the function? Just out of curiosity, is there a way to make the x=30 take precedent in the hierarchy over a defined x? Or bring down the user function defined (x=300) below a global defined variable (x <- 100)?

Comment: Set a different default. Figured it all out. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The simplest method would be to set an appropriate default argument:

```
myfunc <- function(x=get("x", globalenv())
{
    x
}

> x <- 100
> f()
[1] 100
> f(30)
[1] 30
> rm(x)
> f()
Error in get("x", globalenv()) : object 'x' not found
```