# Save a list of plots from environment in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, environment-variables, visualization

I want to save all my plots from my R environment with `ggsave()`. **How can I save list of plots from environment in R and then use the list as input to** `ggsave()` ?

I got some plots with `cars` from [here](https://www.datavis.ca/courses/RGraphics/R/gg-cars.html) to illustrate:

```
PlotA <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg, color=cyl, shape=cyl)) +
  geom_point(size=3)

PlotB <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg, color=cyl, shape=cyl)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", aes(fill=cyl)) 

PlotC <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point(size=3, aes(color=cyl, shape=cyl)) +
  geom_smooth(method="loess", color="black", se=FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", aes(color=cyl, fill=cyl))
```

- My attempt:

```
saveplots <- list()
saveplots <- ls(pattern = 'Plot')

### Save pngs ###

for(i in 1:length(saveplots)){
  ggsave(saveplots[[i]],
         file=paste0("Total", saveplots,".png"),
         width = 22, height = 11.5, units = "cm",
         path = "plots/")
}
```

- Some posts helped a bit, but not  quite yet ([ex1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167607/r-get-object-from-global-environment-from-function-if-object-exists-in-global-bu) [ex2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599366/r-get-objects-from-environment-and-feed-to-function)). Any ideas? Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `get` to get the object from the environment.

```
for(i in 1:length(saveplots)){
  ggsave(plot = get(saveplots[[i]]),
         filename=paste0("Total", saveplots[[i]],".png"),
         width = 22, height = 11.5, units = "cm",
         path = "plots/")
}
```

Comment: yess! it's working! thank you very much!! (just one thing = I had a typo in the original post, now I've removed *~* in the path :)

Answer (score 2):

Another similar way using `lapply` with `ls` and `get`:

```
plots_list <- lapply(ls(pattern="Plot"), get)

lapply(seq_along(plots_list), function(i) {
  ggsave(paste0("Total", i, ".png"), plots_list[[i]], width=22, height=11.5, units="cm", path = "plots/")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `mget`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
mget(savePlots) %>%
    iwalk(~ ggsave(str_c("Total", .y, ".png"), 
               .x, width = 22, height = 11.5, units = "cm", path = "plots/"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative if you don't know/remember/care what the names of all your `ggplot`s are,  try   `saveplots <- lsclass('ggplot')` .  It's available in my package (at CRAN)  "cgwtools" ;  source provided here:

```
lsclass <- function (type = "numeric") 
{
    inlist <- ls(.GlobalEnv)
    classlist <- sapply(1:length(inlist), function(j) class(get(inlist[j])))
    tnams <- sapply(1:length(inlist), function(j) type %in% classlist[[j]])
    return(inlist[tnams])
}
```